# Export table of all versions of list items

Tags: 2007, export, version-history

Using SharePoint 2007, and I only have client-side access.  I can view all versions of each item in a list by using the **IncludeVersions** parameter as follows:

```
http://wss/XYZ/sites/SomeSPSite/ThisList/Forms/AllItems.aspx?IncludeVersions=TRUE
```

But when I export this list to a spreadsheet, only the most recent version shows up.  Is there a way I can export the **IncludeVersions** view to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

The steps found on this post helped me in the past.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561661/sharepoint-list-version-history-export-to-excel

> While I haven't found a clean way of doing this, I have a partial
>   workaround.
>
> 1. Use the Export to Excel option in the List section of the ribbon (make sure the list view you export includes a modified column -
>      thanks T6J2E5).
> 2. Save the owssvr.iqy file and open with notepad
> 3. Copy just the URL from the file and paste it back into your browser, adding "&IncludeVersions=TRUE"
> 4. Save the XML file and open in Excel (or your favorite XML viewer), selecting the "As an XML table" open option.
> 5. You'll have to delete the first few columns and rows as they contain the schema data but other than that you should have all the
>      version history (I suggest you add the Version column to the view).
>      You can sort by the Modified column to get a chronological change
>      log of the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool that might help:  http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/11/import-export-copy-and-delete-list-items/  I'm not sure if the resulting export files can be opened in excel but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No". I ran into a similar problem a few weeks back and there are no good options with SharePoint 2007 to get the versions of documents or list items.

The solution I finally chose was to write a code based on lists.asmx to get the version history of each list item column-by-column.

Do let me know if you had found any better solutions.

Comment: Our ad-hoc solution ended up being a workflow task that adds an item to a list every time a document gets checked in, so that each item in the list represents one version of one document's metadata.  Not ideal, because if the workflow ever gets turned off, the list won't be current.